# Prestashop Backend Error 500 after Migration

Tags: migration, prestashop, http-status-code-500

After migrating Prestashop to another server and domain everything works fine except the Backend.
Urls are correctly setup in database
Cache has been cleared
No .htaccess available
Anyway i get Error 500

This is the backend url http://pasticceriagiovaec.com/admin990nkzwve/

When PS_MODE_DEV true then i get:

```
in classes.php line 93
at ErrorHandler->handleError('2', 'session_cache_limiter(): Cannot change cache limiter when headers already sent', '/home/qkpastic/public_html/app/cache/dev/classes.php', '93', array('options' => array('cookie_httponly' => true, 'gc_probability' => '1'), 'handler' => null, 'metaBag' => object(MetadataBag)))
at session_cache_limiter('') in classes.php line 93
at NativeSessionStorage->__construct(array('cookie_httponly' => true, 'gc_probability' => '1'), null, object(MetadataBag)) in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 4362
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSession_Storage_NativeService() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2248
at Container->get('session.storage.native') in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 4323
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSessionService() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2248
at Container->get('session') in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3990
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_Csrf_TokenManagerService() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2248
at Container->get('security.csrf.token_manager') in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3280
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getPrestashop_RouterService() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2248
at Container->get('prestashop.router', '2') in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 2160
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getLocaleListenerService() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2248
at Container->get('locale_listener') in classes.php line 1962
at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->lazyLoad('kernel.finish_request') in classes.php line 1930
at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->getListeners('kernel.finish_request') in TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 245
at TraceableEventDispatcher->preProcess('kernel.finish_request') in TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 135
at TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.finish_request', object(FinishRequestEvent)) in bootstrap.php.cache line 3273
at HttpKernel->finishRequest(object(Request), '1') in bootstrap.php.cache line 3212
at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', false) in bootstrap.php.cache line 3360
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', false) in bootstrap.php.cache line 2562
at Kernel->handle(object(Request), '1', false) in index.php line 86
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a Symphony cache issue to me - Try emptying the whole **/app/cache/** folder and see if it helps.

Also the /app/cache/ folder is from buggy 1.7.2.x < tree... Consider updating to latest version.

Comment: So i've cleared the whole app/cache/ folder and downgraded PHP version to 7.2

Now there's just one more error:

FatalErrorException in AdminDashboardController.php line 29:
Compile Error: Declaration of AdminDashboardControllerCore::setMedia() must be compatible with AdminControllerCore::setMedia($isNewTheme = false)

Comment: Ok i've solved it downgrading to PHP 7.1
thanks for your help!